# How to allow multiple step definitions match

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I am using cucumber for BDD testing and the feature file looks as follows:

```
Feature: Sing Up

  Scenario: User tries to sign up without interests 
    Given the interests are empty
    When user presses on sign up
    Then it should show "The interests field is empty."

  Scenario: User tries to sign up with 2 interests 
    Given 2 interests are entered
    When user presses on sign up
    Then it should show "The interests should be at least three."
```

The I've created the steps in JS:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const { Given, When, Then } = require("cucumber");

Given("the interests are empty", function() {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  return "pending";
});

When("user presses on sign up", function() {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  return "pending";
});

Then("it should show {string}", function(string) {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  return "pending";
});

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

Given("{int} interests are entered", function(int) {
  // Given('{float} interests are entered', function (float) {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  return "pending";
});

When("user presses on sign up", function() {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  return "pending";
});

Then("it should show {string}", function(string) {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  return "pending";
});
```

The compiler complains:

```
   ✖ When user presses on sign up
       Multiple step definitions match:
         user presses on sign up - features/step_definitions/signup/steps.js:9 
         user presses on sign up - features/step_definitions/signup/steps.js:27
```

How to allow same `when` in different `scenario`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your step definitions have to be unique and you don't have to redefine them per scenario. The compiler tells that your `user presses on sign up` step has been defined twice (same with `it should show {string}`).

Comment: In other words, delete both of the duplicates; the single definition will be run by both scenarios.

Comment: @MikeCollins So what happens if 2 of my scenario has one step which has the same words in both of the scenario but does 2 different things depending upon the scenario in place. Anyway to override step definition per scenario?

Comment: @taimuralam no, I don't think this is possible. The Cucumber parser doesn't have a mechanism for telling it to prefer one matching step definition over another. I've never come across a scenario where this would be required - feel free to open another question with the details and perhaps I can provide more insight.